# Ошибка 'bitrix:system.auth.authorize' is not a component

Tags: битрикс

Два сервера. На первом создал резервную копию - на втором развернул через BitrixVM. Операционки на 90 процентов идентичные (centos). При заходе на сайт появляется ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите куда копать. Какие логи смотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего проверить наличие /bitrix/components/bitrix/
и /bitrix/components/bitrix/system.auth.authorize/

Возможно проблема в бекапе.